# What type of function does the Node.JS REPL evaluates even before I hit enter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I noticed that sometimes in the Node.JS REPL, it evaluates the result of the current expression,
[even before I hit enter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bauON.png)

But that behavior puzzles me: How does it know if I wanted to evaluate it or not? I know it doesn't hurt to evaluate 4+5, but what if it was [a function that involved heavy calculations?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XNAK.png) Wouldn't it slow down my machine? And even worse, what if the function messed with some internal state, like a global variable?

I tried to google with, with no success. I noticed two interesting things, though: When I try to evaluate Fibonacci recursively, it evaluates until Fib(30), but not [Fib(31)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ycMy.png). My guess is that if the function takes too long to compute, Node.JS gives up on giving us a "preview". But I'm not so sure of how that works internally.

I tried googling it with little success. So, how does Node.JS knows exactly if it should evaluate an expression? Is there a name for that "result preview" we see before we hit enter? Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Node.js has the ability (via V8, the JavaScript engine it uses) to know what your function does and doesn't do -- for instance, whether it's a pure function (like `Math.min`) or a function with side effects (like `someArray.push`), and how complex it is. Other than quoting what the source code does (both Node.js and V8 are open source, not that the source is easy to read :-) ), I'm not sure what more someone can tell you other than what you already seem to know.. (Except that this is not something you can do from your JavaScript code.)

Comment: But fundamentally, my guess is if it's a pure function, it runs it but kills it when it reaches some arbitrary time or memory limit; and if it isn't a pure function, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That feature is called eager evaluation and you can learn more about it on [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/20977).

When you type an expression, that expression is evaluated with a timeout (to prevent heavy computations) and with the restriction that, if the expression would cause a side-effect, the evaluation is stopped. ([code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/6bdf8d106009e4ed0f3c323d0f0874a51acc8e08/lib/internal/repl/utils.js#L146-L151))

Comment: That's pretty smart!! Do you know by any chance if it's possible to change the value of the timeout or even disable it? I'm curious to know if it is something hard-coded or not. But anyway, your response is pretty much everything I wanted to know.

Comment: @diksown You can edit the source code and recompile Node.js, but that isn't very convenient. You can also just edit the binary directly with a text editor, find `session.post('Runtime.evaluate'` and replace the characters for the timeout. Just be careful not to insert or delete any characters, so the length remains unchanged.